# Using blasters against AT-ATs?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, blasters

I've just rewatched *Star Wars Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back*, and during the Battle of Hoth, a rebel soldier said that the AT-AT shields were too strong for blasters. If that is so, why did they continue shooting? Is it to distract the walkers? Or was it for another reason?

And if there are things that are blaster-proof in Star Wars, why aren't there many people who keep weapons that aren't blasters, like normal guns?

Comment: The same reason crooks used to not only shoot bullets at Superman, but try to throw the guns at him in the old TV show. They *know* he can't be hurt, but what else are they going to do?

Comment: @phantom42 I guess that makes sense...

Comment: Additionally, in the games at least, the shielding on vehicles and such can be worn down by blaster fire; it just takes a lot of it.

Comment: When the only tool you have is a blaster, everything looks like a blaster target...

Comment: @phantom42 - so, bad writing?

Comment: @Davor, no, not bad writing. Realistic writing. That's what combatants do under stress, in general terms. People shoot small arms at tanks, not because of the small chance they have of getting lucky and actually doing something effective, but because, hey, I have a gun and there's something big coming towards me. I'll scream in desperation that it's not working, but I'll keep shooting anyway.

Comment: @JoãoMendes - I don't know, from my experience, people run away when running away is available and winning isn't. The "screaming banzai" is very much a movie trope in my experience.

Comment: @Davor Sure, that happens too. Eventually, people realize they can (and should?) run away, and they do. As I recall, that happened in the scene as well. :) (Though I may be wrong on that count, it's been a while since I've watched it.)

Comment: The other pertinent example to consider is the Battle of Endor. Fuzzy teddy bear creatures with spears and rocks against a legion of the Emperor's best troops? Smart fighting against an overwhelming/overpowering enemy can still win.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the quote was "That armor's too strong for blasters" implying that most of the body can withstand lots of blasts.  This is similar to current day tanks which can take lots of punishment from small arms fire but can still be penetrated by lucky shots in one of its many vulnerable parts, such as the turret swivel, tracks and sensors.  Being in a tank while it is being shot at by a machine gun is very distracting.

There is a scene where a blast from someone in the trench shot at, and hit, a rear leg joint causing a large (relatively speaking) explosion.

Another point I remember from my Marine Corp days is that having as many guns firing at the same time has an effect of causing attackers to concentrate fire towards your main fortification so that a flanking attack has a better chance of success.  The flanking attack by the snow speeders in this case.

This particular battle is also a rear guard action, so killing is not the objective, just slowing down the attack.  For that purpose, the more guns firing, the better.

All in all, this scene looks like the first encounter German Forces had with English tanks in WWI.  Machine guns were fired at the tanks and managed to stop a lot of them.

Comment: To supplement this answer, regarding the point about tanks in WWI:  machine guns were effective against the early tanks, not because the bullets pierced the hull (they didn't), but because they caused white-hot shards of metal to flake off the interior walls and ricochet around inside the tank, wounding the occupants.  The same idea might apply here.

Comment: @WadCheber: That effect is called "spalling", and has never ceased to be an issue. It's what makes even crude IED's a threat to modern tanks. Indeed, the British created an AT round that is not *intended* to penetrate, but cause maximum spalling (HESH).

Comment: they were also shooting at the AT-STs and foot soldiers

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and it makes me look forward to any other answers you might have about the Star Wars movies. :)